# WPF Enabled and disable Button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, wpf-controls

I am doing the code using MVVM pattern

I have two buttons Add and Remove

when i click on the add button it add the list of information which is binded to some property .

I want the remove button should only be enabled if there is any information in the list

For eg

When I click Add button it creates a list

List of people
 1. Ram
 2. Sam
 3. Dam

When I Click on "Remove" Button it will remove each items one by one , when everything is remove the button will again become disabled

Expectation -

I just want the Remove button to be disabled till there is nothing in the list to be removed

Whenever Something is added in a list the button Should become Enabled .

Comment: _I want a [packet of Tim Tams that never runs out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoggSVxghWs)_ . Welcome to SO. Please don't post requirements and like Tim Tims, expect code to magically appear. Any code to show? What research have you done? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are really trying to do, but for what I understand:

You have a list, where items get added after clicking the add button.
I assume this happens in the Button_Click event. This is the place where you enable/show the button like:

```
RemoveButton.Visibility = Visibilty.Visible;
RemoveButton.IsEnabled = true;
```

And then in the clickevent of the remove button you can loop over the list and remove all the items. At the end of the loop you can disable the remove button again.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    private void CreateAddCommand()
    {
        CancelCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteCancel, CanExecuteCancelCommand);
    }

    private void ExecuteAdd(object obj)
    {
       //Here is Your code
    }

    private bool CanExecuteAddCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true;//return the value based on conditions here is button enable or desabled condition.
    }
```

in constructor call CreateAddCommand();

and xaml code like

```
<Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Background="#FFF38181" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" Height="30"/>
```